# How to subset all rows in a dataframe that have a particular value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a large dataset that contains in each row different combinations of "NA" "1" and "2". I would like to subset all rows that specifically contain only "2" and "NA".

So in the sample below, I'd like to automatically name and subset Row1 and Row4:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1=c(NA,NA,2,NA),
                 Col2=c(NA,NA,1,2),
                 Col3=c(NA,1,NA,NA),
                 Col4=c(2,NA,NA,NA),
                 row.names=c("Row1","Row2","Row3","Row4"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work because the "2" can be in any column, not just in column "x".

Comment: After the question has been enhanced by sample data, it shouldn't have been closed, IMHO.

Comment: I was just about to post `df[!rowSums(df != 2, na.rm = TRUE), ]` as well as `row.names(df[!rowSums(df != 2, na.rm = TRUE), ])` as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
target <- 2

#print row names
names(which(apply(df, 1, function(x) all(na.omit(x)==target))==TRUE))
[1] "Row1" "Row4"

#subset rows
df_sub <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(na.omit(x)==target)),]

print(df_sub)
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Row1   NA   NA   NA    2
Row4   NA    2   NA   NA
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1=c(NA,NA,2,NA),
                 Col2=c(NA,NA,1,2),
                 Col3=c(NA,1,NA,NA),
                 Col4=c(2,NA,NA,NA),
                 row.names=c("Row1","Row2","Row3","Row4"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, almost, I wanted to add an example but I don't know how to edit my own question (...) My dataframe has row names, so I would like to obtain the row names of the selected rows as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer accordingly, and I edited your question for you.

Comment: If you just want to drop the rows containing 1 you could do `df[!apply(df,1,'%in%',x=1 ),]`